# Unable to create sendGrid Resource in azure

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I am unable to create sendGrid in azure. I can't get pass review legal terms. the console give's me this error:

Subscription ID: 0bccce40-dd06-4ae7-8069-b75f37b14445
Products: Sendgrid:sendgrid_azure
GetSpecsCosts status code: BatchFailed
Ratings API error code: BadRequest

I have contacted sendGrid support and they direct me to azure. To get any technical help from azure i need to upgrade my support plan :(

Has any one else had this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ff6a494b-9909-4693-87d6-73ecf4d681ac/cant-create-sendgrid-account-from-azure-portal?forum=DataMarket) on the MSDN Forums, you should raise a support request [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=classiccommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=16230&forceorigin=esmc&ccsid=636783026157427051) with

- Problem type: *Marketplace  Onboarding*
- Category: *Technical Marketplace query*

Next to this, you have a couple of ways to get Azure support without upgrading your support plan.

**Twitter**
This is the simplest and probably fastest way to contact [Azure Support](https://twitter.com/azuresupport). They're really fast and can help you with most issues or direct you to the right channels when they can't.

**MSDN Forums**
You can search the [Azure MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?category=windowsazureplatform) or post your question there.

**Stack Overflow**
You can search [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or post your question there.

**All options**
Review all your [Azure Support options](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/) here.

*Status*
By the way: I just tried creating a SendGrid resource in Azure and everything seemed to work fine. This means it doesn't seem to be an Azure issue, so there might be something wrong with the data you provided, or the rights you have, or ...

[image: SendGrid accounts]